# ScrollView is not working in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview

I have this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root_ll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And this code-behind below, everything is generated perfectly but the screen is not scrollable, can you tell me what the problem is? Thanks.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_ll);
for(int i = 0; i < 6 i++)
{
            LinearLayout llInside= new LinearLayout(this);
            llInside.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            llInside.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            WebView wView = new WebView(this);


            TextView tvInside = new TextView(this);
                    wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.gif");
                    setContentView(wView);
                    tvInside.setText("A");

 wView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    600,
                    600));

            tvInside.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 74);

            if(wView.getParent()!=null)
                ((ViewGroup)wView.getParent()).removeView(wView);

            if(tvInside.getParent()!=null)
                ((ViewGroup)tvInside.getParent()).removeView(tvInside);

            llInside.addView(wView);
            llInside.addView(tvInside);




            if(llInside.getParent()!=null)
                  ((ViewGroup)llInside.getParent()).removeView(llInside);

            linearLayout.addView(llInside);


            // linearLayout.addView(wView);
            //make visible to program



}
    if(linearLayout.getParent()!=null)
            ((ViewGroup)linearLayout.getParent()).removeView(linearLayout);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
```

Comment: where is the scrollview

Comment: @RanjitPati edited the question

Comment: can you change scrollView height to wrap_content

Comment: there are no control buttons in scrollview, so how it might be working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calls to `setContentView()` are the problem. That method sets the layout for the Activity. Every time your code calls it, it's completely replacing the Activity's content, and your `ScrollView` is long gone. Remove all calls to `setContentView()` in the posted code, as well as the following:

```
if(linearLayout.getParent()!=null)
    ((ViewGroup)linearLayout.getParent()).removeView(linearLayout);
```

You can also remove the null checks on the parent `View`s for the `View`s you're creating dynamically, as they won't have parents until you add them.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_ll);
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    LinearLayout llInside= new LinearLayout(this);
    llInside.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    llInside.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                                 AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    WebView wView = new WebView(this);

    TextView tvInside = new TextView(this);
    wView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.gif");

    tvInside.setText("A");

    wView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                              600,
                              600));

    tvInside.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 74);

    llInside.addView(wView);
    llInside.addView(tvInside);

    linearLayout.addView(llInside);
}
```

Comment: Well thank you but setContentView()s are crucial for that part of code, do you have any other idea for this? How can I set the view of the content without using them?

Comment: That method sets the content for the whole Activity. As soon as you call `setContentView(wView);`, your Activity contains only a WebView, and your original layout is gone. Normally, that method is only called once, in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Trust me. Just comment out those lines and try it.

Comment: all SetContentViews and removeViews? I suppose the code will not do what it's supposed to do. But I will try anyway

Comment: When I remove SetContentView parts, there becomes nothing to show on the screen

Comment: I've posted your code with the offending lines removed. If your code looks like this and you still don't see anything, then you've got a problem elsewhere. I just tested it.

Comment: Man, you are a life-saver. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have use:

`android:layout_height="fill_parent";`

And for `ScrollView` use:

`android:layout_height="wrap_content";`

Then its work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_ll2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root_ll"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

 your buttons ,etc...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @murugaloner does root_ll have to be RelativeLayout, if yes, why?

Comment: Will it make sense ?? explain the reason for root as relative layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change a little in heights only..just make all to `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/root_ll"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

And make sure the whole content height is more than screen height.

**EDIT**

As WebViews are scrollable. You just use `LinearLayout` only..No need to use ScrollView here.

Comment: I was using LinearLayout at first, it wasn't working at all... I don't want WebViews to be scrollable I only want my root layout to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/root_ll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeaderTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is TextView in your layout necessary?

Comment: bro, it's not necessary, this is just for the knowledge that scrollview is working fine. That's why I added it to the layout.

Comment: no it didn't work, only Hello World textview is appearing

Comment: but I have put the only one textview, that's why it is scrolling, check it and let me know, i have done it into my app.

Comment: I have given the temp height for linearlayout is 1000, so you can it that listview is working or not?

Comment: Yeah, I applied all of your code, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95433/discussion-between-parth-bhayani-and-jason).

Comment: Hey, try this, I have checked it and it is working,try pasting again and it working fine.

Comment: Hey, paste the whole code and after that  clean your code and run it.